# How is this probability converging?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

> Let $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$,...$X_{n}$ be independent random variables that are uniformly distributed over [-1,1]. Show that
>   $$ Y_{n}= X_{n}/n $$
>   Converges to some limit, and identify the limit.

I have

$$ P(|Y_{n}|\geq \varepsilon)=P(|X_{n}/n|\geq \varepsilon) <P(|1/n|\geq \varepsilon)\rightarrow 0 $$

When I look at the solution, I saw that the proof is concluded with:

"...for all $n$ with $ \dfrac1n < \varepsilon$."

It appears there is contradiction in my proof because $\varepsilon$ can not be both less or equal to $1/n$ and greater than $1/n$.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to show convergence in probability, we have for any $\varepsilon > 0$ $$P(|Y_{n}|\geq \varepsilon)=P(|X_{n}/n|\geq \varepsilon)  = P(|X_n| \geq n\varepsilon) =  0 \; \;  \forall \; n \ge \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$$

Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|Y_{n}|\geq \varepsilon) \to 0$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: @AmosKu: If you are satisfied, kindly accept the answer.